# Handling lost focus in Dart

Tags: html, focus, dart

How to handle lost focus in dart? For example, if some code runs on the page and users (for example) minimizes the window or switches to another tab, the current page looses focus. Is there some method that fires up in this case I can override in my code?

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what you are doing. Some code example that allows to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Well it's not some specific problem. I was asking if there is some method I can override that fires when the window looses focus.

Comment: If someone already had the same problem he might provide some help. From your question I have not the slightest idea what your problem is about.

Comment: I'll try to specify it a bit more.

Comment: The question has been edited.

Comment: Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008 ?

Comment: Yes, but are the same functions available in dart?

Comment: I didn't take a closer look because I dont't know if this is what you are looking for but if you can do it in JS there is a way in Dart too (for the worst case there is dart-js-interop)

Comment: I was looking for something more 'built-in' than dart-js-interop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
import 'dart:html' as dom;
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  dom.document.onVisibilityChange.listen(visibilityChangeHandler);
  dom.window.onFocus.listen(focusHandler);
  dom.window.onBlur.listen(blurHandler);
}

void visibilityChangeHandler(dom.Event e) {
  print('visibility changed: $e');
}

void focusHandler(dom.Event e) {
  print('focus: $e');
}

void blurHandler(dom.Event e) {
  print('blur: $e');
}
```

see also [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008)

Comment: I'll try and share the result.

Comment: Great! I already tried it and it works for minimizing but not for lost focus. I'm currently trying `document.onFocus`.

Comment: I've tried switching to other tabs and it fires the method. Thats basically what I wanted.

Comment: The other events are on `window` not `document`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes. Looks like onBlur works even better for my case. Thanks very much :)